# How would one find the direction a stair goes to in an array?

Tags: math, rust

In Fire Emblem, the maps displayed have stairs that go certain directions, like so:

[image: FE3HMap]

Here the map has stairs indicated by lines looking like either of these: `|||` or `≡`. I have a grid of these tiles/terrain, and there's no information about the direction of these stairs, however we can gather the direction of the stairs depending on some things:

1. The neighboring stair tiles
2. The neighboring non-stair tiles

If a stair has stairs up and/or down of it, the stair points vertically `≡`. If a stair has stairs left and/or right of it, it points horizontally `|||`.

In the cases where 2 directions (for example if up neighbor and left neighbor are stairs) have stairs, or no directions have stairs, we use the other tiles to determine the stairs direction. The stair CANNOT go to the direction of a tile that has a TerrainGroup of LowObstacle or HighObstacle (The blue water is a low obstacle and the the grey borders are walls which are also low obstacles). To get the TerrainGroup I have a function named `get_terrain_group`. I've attempt to implement this in rust, but I'm having issues with the correctness of the code:

```rust
fn stair_direction(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> ColoredString {
        // Check neighboring tiles
        let mut has_up_neighbor = false;
        let mut has_down_neighbor = false;
        let mut has_left_neighbor = false;
        let mut has_right_neighbor = false;

        // Check up tile
        if y > 0 {
            let up_index = (y - 1) * self.width + x;
            if let Terrain::Stairs = self.board[up_index] {
                has_up_neighbor = true;
            } else {
                let up_group = get_terrain_group(&self.board[up_index]);
                if up_group == TerrainGroup::LowObstacle || up_group == TerrainGroup::HighObstacle {
                    has_up_neighbor = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Check down tile
        if y < self.height - 1 {
            let down_index = (y + 1) * self.width + x;
            if let Terrain::Stairs = self.board[down_index] {
                has_down_neighbor = true;
            } else {
                let down_group = get_terrain_group(&self.board[down_index]);
                if down_group == TerrainGroup::LowObstacle
                    || down_group == TerrainGroup::HighObstacle
                {
                    has_down_neighbor = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Check left tile
        if x > 0 {
            let left_index = y * self.width + (x - 1);
            if let Terrain::Stairs = self.board[left_index] {
                has_left_neighbor = true;
            } else {
                let left_group = get_terrain_group(&self.board[left_index]);
                if left_group == TerrainGroup::LowObstacle
                    || left_group == TerrainGroup::HighObstacle
                {
                    has_left_neighbor = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Check right tile
        if x < self.width - 1 {
            let right_index = y * self.width + (x + 1);
            if let Terrain::Stairs = self.board[right_index] {
                has_right_neighbor = true;
            } else {
                let right_group = get_terrain_group(&self.board[right_index]);
                if right_group == TerrainGroup::LowObstacle
                    || right_group == TerrainGroup::HighObstacle
                {
                    has_right_neighbor = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Determine stair direction
        if has_up_neighbor || has_down_neighbor {
            // Vertical
            "|||".on_black()
        } else {
            // Horizontal
            "≡≡≡".on_black()
        }
    }
```

Pretend as if ColoredString is &str instead if that works. Also heres the skeleton for the GameBoard struct which this method is in:

```rust
pub struct GameBoard {
    board: Vec<Terrain>,
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
}
```

My implementation doesn't work fully and has issues resulting in this output:
[image]

You can see how it differs from the original image, especially the stairs with no stair neighbors.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong in this function for this?
Also I'm aware that certain configurations don't fulfill any of the criteria I've specified, in that case return some default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the map you've shown, the stairs are vertical if at least one of the right or left field is empty and horizontal if at least one of the up and down field is empty. So this should work:

```
fn stair_direction(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> ColoredString {
    // Assume the stairs are horizontal
    let mut horizontal = true;

    /// Check the left and right fields, if either is empty then
    /// the stairs were vertical after all
    if x > 0 {
        let left_index = y * self.width + (x - 1);
        let left_group = get_terrain_group(&self.board[left_index]);
        if !matches!(self.board[left_index], Terrain::Stairs)
           && left_group != TerrainGroup::LowObstacle
           && left_group != TerrainGroup::HighObstacle
        {
            horizontal = false;
        }
    }
    if x < self.width - 1 {
        let right_index = y * self.width + (x + 1);
        let right_group = get_terrain_group(&self.board[right_index]);
        if !matches!(self.board[right_index], Terrain::Stairs)
           && right_group != TerrainGroup::LowObstacle
           && right_group != TerrainGroup::HighObstacle
        {
            horizontal = false;
        }
    }
    
    if horizontal {
        "≡≡≡".on_black()
    } else {
        "|||".on_black()
    }
}
```

This should work in all situations unless a field is completely surrounded by stairs, in which case it will give horizontal stairs even if the surrounding stairs are vertical.

Answer (score 1):

If a terrain field isn't stairs you never set it to true even if it's not an obstacle, I think you want unoccupied fields to count as neighbours, too:

```rust
if y > 0 {
    let up_index = (y - 1) * self.width + x;
    if let Terrain::Stairs = self.board[up_index] {
        has_up_neighbor = true;
    } else {
        let up_group = get_terrain_group(&self.board[up_index]);
        has_up_neighbor = !(up_group == TerrainGroup::LowObstacle || up_group == TerrainGroup::HighObstacle);
    }
}
```

and similar for the other directions.

Comment: I've used this but it seems to not work, I've even tried the following:

`if y > 0 {
            let up_index = (y - 1) * self.width + x;
            let up_group = get_terrain_group(&self.board[up_index]);
            has_up_neighbor =
                !(up_group == TerrainGroup::LowObstacle || up_group == TerrainGroup::HighObstacle);
        }`

Since stairs are not low obstacles or high obstacles either.